# Chrome Extension: Clear Chrome Local Storage on Page Reload (not on Update)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I'm working on a Chrome Extension that will sort a DOM structure. On the extension popup I'm using a button that will activate / desactivate the sort. In order to save the state of my button I'm saving via Chrome Local Storage the "state" of my button this way:

```
function save_button_state() {
  var buttonStateText = $("#js-toggleSorting").html();
  var buttonStateAttribute = $("#js-toggleSorting").attr("data-click-state");
  var sortMessage = $(".message").html();
  chrome.storage.local.set(
    {
      buttonStateText: buttonStateText,
      buttonStateAttribute: buttonStateAttribute,
      sortMessage: sortMessage,
    },
    function () {
      console.log(
        `Saved State is: ${buttonStateText} and Saved Attribute is: ${buttonStateAttribute} and Saved Message is: ${sortMessage}`
      );
    }
  );
}
```

That save the dom node and keep the information in order to save it when the popup is closed. Then, in order to get that info back from the local storage I'm using this function:

```
function get_button_state() {
  chrome.storage.local.get(
    ["buttonStateText", "buttonStateAttribute", "sortMessage"],
    function (data) {
      $(".message").html(data.sortMessage);
      $("#js-toggleSorting").html(data.buttonStateText);
      $("#js-toggleSorting").attr(
        "data-click-state",
        data.buttonStateAttribute
      );
      console.log(
        `Get State is ${data.buttonStateText} and Get Attribute is ${data.buttonStateAttribute}`
      );
    }
  );
}
```

And then when the document is ready I'm processing the button onclick event changing the dom from "Sorting" to "Not Sorting" this way:

```
$(document).ready(() => {
  get_button_state();
  //Some Code to pass parameters from the extension to a content script
  $("#js-toggleSorting").on("click", function () {
    $(".message").html("");
    if ($(this).attr("data-click-state") == 1) {
      $(this).attr("data-click-state", 0);
      $(this).html("SORT INCOMING CHATS");
      $(".message").append("<p>STATUS: NOT SORTING CHATS</p>");
      sortFunction(false);
    } else {
      $(this).attr("data-click-state", 1);
      $(this).html("STOP SORTING INCOMING CHATS");
      $(".message").append("<p>STATUS: SORTING CHATS</p>");
      sortFunction(true);
    }
    save_button_state();
  });
});
```

Then in the Chrome Extension background js file I'm trying to clear the local storage when I reload the page (the same page, with the same URL):

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (changeInfo) {
  if (changeInfo.url === undefined) {
    chrome.storage.local.clear();
  }
});
```

But apparently this will not only clear the local storage when I reload the page but when something change in it causing a lot of buggy behavior on the popup (basically changing very randomly the text of the button when the user interact/click on it everytime they open the popup). My question is which is the right way to clear the local storage just when the page is reloaded / refreshed. I'm sorry if this seems pretty obvious but I'm new on the Chrome Extension development world.